# How to launch protractor instance multiple times from Grunt task

Tags: gruntjs, protractor

I am trying to launch protractor multiple times from a grunt task like this

```
grunt.registerTask('makeapps', 'Create Apps', function(count) {

      console.log('value of count is' + count);
      var done=this.async();

      for(var i=1 ;i <= count; i++)
      {

              grunt.initConfig({

              protractor: {
                options: {
                  configFile: "./createAppConf.js", // Default config file which includes protractor tests and other dependencies such as HTML protractor screenshot reporter
                  keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
                  noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
                  args: {
                    // Arguments passed to the command
                  }

                },
                your_target: {   // Grunt requires at least one target to run so you can simply put 'all: {}' here too.
                  options: {
                    configFile: "createAppConf.js", // // Default config file which includes protractor tests and other dependencies such as HTML protractor screenshot reporter
                    args: {} // Target-specific arguments
                  }
                },
              },
             })

              grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
       }  

       done();

});
```

I run the task like this

> grunt makeapps:3 protractor

I am able to launch protractor and the  test once only. I am not able to launch it multiple times. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your solution would run the function you have *and* the protractor task defined alongside it. Grunt is more declarative, it first collects task definitions and then you can trigger them.

What about using https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-concurrent or https://github.com/iammerrick/grunt-parallel?